# Single Array & Data Plotting with it

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

The data I have is printed in a .txt file format and has breaks in between readings, its just one really long line. Each data point is a 16 second average of the z-component of the magnetic field of an incoming particle field. This is currently the code I have typed to ascribe the variable name to the file

```
Bz = np.loadtxt(r'C:\Users\Schmidt\Desktop\Project\Data\ACE\MAG\ACE_MAG_Data.txt', dtype = str)
```

and that works fine, but when I ask to print Bz I get

```
[["b'-1.3695e+01'" "b'-1.3481e+01'"]
["b'-1.3804e+01'" "b'-1.3485e+01'"]
["b'-1.3704e+01'" "b'-1.3437e+01'"]
..., 
["b'1.6371e+00'" "b'6.2744e-01'"]
["b'1.6171e+00'" "b'6.1338e-01'"]
["b'1.4028e+00'" "b'3.2874e-01'"]]
```

What my problem is how did that "b" get there in the first place and how do I tell python that each data point is an individual point instead of pairs like it has it now.

[This is the link to the file if you need to see.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cev5stizmzu4w07/ACE_MAG_Data.txt?dl=0) Just remember to remove the words and the file should act appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

numpy is loading your data as bytes, and marking them as such, with the b character. I tried the following:

```
data = np.loadtxt("ACE_MAG_Data.txt", dtype=bytes).astype(float)
```

And it converts everything to floats instead:

```
>>> data
array([[-13.695  , -13.481  ],
       [-13.804  , -13.485  ],
       [-13.704  , -13.437  ],
       ..., 
       [  1.6371 ,   0.62744],
       [  1.6171 ,   0.61338],
       [  1.4028 ,   0.32874]])
```

You mention that these are individual points, not pairs. If you had saved them as points in the file, one per line, numpy wouldn't assume these are pairs - I would too :)

However:

```
singles = [point for pair in data for point in pair]
```

Will convert it to a list of single points.

Comment: almost, I just don't need it in pairs. Its a 1 row and N column data. not a 2 row sort of thing

Comment: the singles variable in my code is a single list of items - if that's not what you're looking for, can you give an example of how you want this data?

Comment: No you were right. It is actually is working! woo! But now my plot is not working :| I had set up my time axis to be an interval from 0 to 5400 (times 16 = seconds per day) as
time = np.arange(5400)
but I don't think that is the right way about this.

Comment: I'm no numpy expert and don't know how time axis works, but bear in mind you now no longer have 5,400 items - you now have 10,800